I am getting error while importing Carousel from react-bootstrap
The error says "[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "components/ExampleCarouselImage" from "src/components/Carousel.jsx". Does the file exist?"

Can you post code for your component ?

The very first carousel on react-bootstrap.
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/carousel

hey, have you fixed the problem yet? i'm having the same issue and looking for help as well... didnt find any solution so far
